# How to use beginMoveRows with alternate indexes

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qml, qt5

I am using a custom `QAbstractItemModel` with a `QTableView` (c++) and `GridView` (QML). My model allows multiple rows selection, including alternate selection (f.e: holding CTRL).

I have implemented Drag&Drop for resorting items. When the selection has non contiguous items, I am calling `beginMoveRows` this way:

```
beginMoveRows(parent, mySeletectedIndexes.first(), mySelectedIndexes.last(), parent, destRow)
```

This is working fine with the `QTableView` but the `GridView` is moving all the items between mySeletectedIndexes.first() and mySeletectedIndexes.last(), even those that don't are being moved. This causes an inconsistency between the model and the view.

How should I use `beginMoveRows` in this case? Are there any other alternatives?

Comment: My guess and first action would be: replace that QML-stuff with what really works.

Comment: I can't replace the GridView. Both views are part of the same application and the user can choose between them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call beginMoveRows() and endMoveRows() for each row separately. Otherwise the QML render has no chance to detect for which rows it should paint the move animation.

Alternatively you could use something like beginResetModel() but this is ugly and you will lose the nice animation.

Comment: Should I call endMoveRows() after every call to beginMoveRows()?, if so I suppose that I have to recalculate the indexes for each row that is going to be moved after the first beginMoveRows() call.